# OpenSCAD editor font is unreadable

Tags: openscad

[image]I am a new OpenSCAD user. My screen editor window is using a very strange font that I cannot read. How can I fix it? I just installed OpenSCAD on my Linux Manjaro computer. 
This is a screen shot of my screen for the first example in the examples folder.

Comment: Have you tried to change the font via:
`Edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> Change to a different font using the combo drop down box?`